# Hard sorting problem - what type of algorithm should I be using?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

**The problem:**

N nodes are related to each other by a 'closeness' factor ranging from 0 to 1, where a factor of 1 means that the two nodes have nothing in common and 0 means the two nodes are exactly alike.

If two nodes are both close to another node (i.e. they have a factor close to 0) then this *doesn't* mean that they will be close together, although probabilistically they do have a much higher chance of being close together.

-

**The question:**

If another node is placed in the set, find the node that it is closest to in the shortest possible amount of time.

This isn't a homework question, this is a real world problem that I need to solve - but I've never taken any algorithm courses etc so I don't have a clue what sort of algorithm I should be researching.

I can index all of the nodes before another one is added and gather closeness data between each node, but short of comparing all nodes to the new node I haven't been able to come up with an efficient solution. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Do the distances between the various existing nodes tell you anything about what the distance between an existing node and the new node might be?  If not, then I think comparing the new node to all existing nodes might be the best you can do.

Comment: Probabilistically, yes, but there is a (very small) chance that this is not the case for some special case nodes. However, as the amount of nodes increases this probability becomes so small that I can possibly ignore it without it ever effecting results.

Comment: If you can think of the nodes as having "fixed locations in space", you could use an octree (or the n-dimensional equivalent if your space has more than three dimensions) to do faster lookups, but it's not clear from your description if they do.

Comment: They do have fixed locations in space. But how about 9000 dimensions - what would efficiency be like? If I model it this way then each node literally has 9000 dimensions

Comment: Does closeness follow the triangle inequality? That is, is D(a,c) >= D(a,b)+D(b,c) for all b? And is closeness actually a real number, or can it be expressed as an integer or a rational?

Comment: @Nick after a bit of thinking, yes. It is measured as a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your 'closeness' metric obeys the triangle inequality, you should be able to use a variant of [BK-Trees](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees) to organize your elements. Adapting them to real numbers should simply be a matter of choosing an interval to quantize your number on, and otherwise using the standard Bk-Tree procedure. Some experimentation may be required - you might want to increase the resolution of the quantization as you progress down the tree, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this method could work really well with some small modifications. An interesting way it'll be used in too - I'll write up a blog post on it once I've got it all working.

Answer (score 1):

> but short of comparing all nodes to
>   the new node I haven't been able to
>   come up with an efficient solution

Without any other information about the relationships between nodes, this is the only way you can do it since you have to figure out the closeness factor between the new node and each existing node. A O(n) algorithm can be a perfectly decent solution.

One addition you might consider - keep in mind we have no idea what data structure you are using for your objects - is to organize all present nodes into a graph, where nodes with factors below a certain threshold can be considered connected, so you can first check nodes that are more likely to be similar/related.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the optimal algorithm in terms of speed, but O(n^2) space, then for each node create a sorted list of other nodes (ordered by closeness).

When you get a new node, you have to add it to the indexed list of all the other nodes, and all the other nodes need to be added to its list.

To find the closest node, just find the first node on any node's list.

Since you already need O(n^2) space (in order to store all the closeness information you need basically an NxN matrix where A[i,j] represents the closeness between i and j) you might as well sort it and get O(1) retrieval.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the retrieving only happens as soon as a new node is added, so would need to be sorted first anyway. Probably my fault for not making the problem description a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If this closeness forms a linear spectrum (such that closeness to something implies closeness to other things that are close to it, and not being close implies not being close to those close), then you can simply do a binary or interpolation sort on insertion for closeness, handling one extra complexity: at each point you have to see if closeness increases or decreases below or above.

For example, if we consider letters - A is close to B but far from Z - then the pre-existing elements can be kept sorted, say: A, B, E, G, K, M, Q, Z.  To insert say 'F', you start by comparing with the middle element, [3] G, and the one following that: [4] K.  You establish that F is closer to G than K, so the best match is either at G or to the left, and we move halfway into the unexplored region to the left... 3/2=[1] B, followed by E, and we find E's closer to F, so the match is either at E or to its right.  Halving the space between our earlier checks at [3] and [1], we test at [2] and find it equally-distant, so insert it in between.

EDIT: it may work better in probabilistic situations, and require less comparisons, to start at the ends of the spectrum and work your way in (e.g. compare F to A and Z, decide it's closer to A, see if A's closer or the halfway point [3] G).  Also, it might be good to finish with a comparison to the closest few points either side of where the binary/interpolation led you.

Comment: Thanks, after a bit of thought this could work. It's not a linear spectrum, but probabilistically it is. At the moment, your approach seems to be a bit like 1 dimensional sorting - but increasing the number of dimensions this sorting happens in would decrease the probability of assumed linearity being wrong. If I can decrease this to a negligible amount, then it should work faster than O(n) - and if this works, then I'll probably write up a blog post on what I'm doing and how the algorithm works ;)

Comment: @Jordan: sounds neat.  Hope you'll update your question with a link to the blog post.  Cheers.

Comment: This assumes that closeness is 1-dimensional (and indeed, dimensional at all). Consider edit distance between words, for instance: It obeys the triangle inequality, but isn't 1-dimensional, or even of any fixed dimension.

Comment: @Nick: yes, that assumption's clearly expressed at the start of the answer.  Ddit distance is a much more complicated problem indeed.

Comment: @Tony Right, but he says "If two nodes are both close to another node (i.e. they have a factor close to 0) then this doesn't mean that they will be close together". Your answer, while useful, assumes a total order over nodes, which doesn't seem likely to be true here.

Comment: @Nick: true... though it continues "although probabilistically they do have a much higher chance ", which is why his comment on my answer above says he'll need to apply this general thinking in a probability-aware multi-dimensional way to see if it works adequately.

Comment: @Nick: by the way, I am not trying to defend this answer as being the best posted or particularly useful... it's a complex problem space and outside my direct experience - I just chipped in with something simple that Nick selected as being a possible basis for a workable solution....

Answer (score 1):

ACM Surveys September 2001 carried two papers that might be relevant, at least for background. "Searching in Metric Spaces", lead author Chavez, and "Searching in High Dimensional Spaces - Index Structures for Improving the Performance of Multimedia Databases", lead author Bohm. From memory, if all you have is the triangle inequality, you can use it to some effect, but if you can trim your data down to a sensible number of dimensions, you can do better by using a search structure that knows about this dimensional structure.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has this thing where it puts you and all of your friends in a graph, then slowly moves everyone around until people are grouped together based on mutual friends and so on.

It looked to me like they just made anything <0.5 an attractive force, anything >0.5 a repulsive force, and moved people with every iteration based on the net force.  After a couple hundred iterations, it was looking pretty darn good.

Note: this is not an algorithm it is a heuristic.  In the facebook implementation I saw, two people were not able to reach equilibrium and kept dancing around each other.  It turns out they were actually the same person with two different accounts.

Also, it took about 15 minutes on a decent computer and ~100 nodes.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

It looks suspiciously like a [Nearest Neighbor Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) problem (also called a `similarity search`)

Comment: Thanks, this is more what I was looking for. Any idea if a 9000 dimension version of this is going to be efficient? - yea, I'm serious :(

Comment: I really only stayed at a Holiday Inn Express - I work with a bunch of insanely smart Machine Learning and Mathmatics folks and learn something from time to time. We do LSH on a 20 node hadoop cluster and k-means on a 16 node MPP Database (all dual-hexacore)... Our datasets are rather large. It really depends on how much hardware you've got but AFAIK it's the most efficient way to do what you're trying to do.